# How can I use R to access files that are within folders, that are in other folders, that are in my working directory?

Tags: r

I need to write a code that allows me to access these files and get information from them. Here's an example of the pathway: Main folder (working directory) -> subject folders -> measurement folders -> excel file. Is there a way I can write some sort of loop that allows me to access the excel files for all of the different measurements from all of the subjects?

already tried listing the files and importing them with a basic for-loop but no success. Not sure how to proceed or if I'm on the right track at all. Note: I don't want to combine them into one dataframe, rather have individual dataframes.

Comment: The `list.files()` function has a `recursive=TRUE` option you can set to search through all subfolders. It's easier to help if you at least show the code you tried and describe exactly what the problem you encountered is. That way we can give a more specific suggestion for improvement.

Comment: So I tried: files <- list.files(pattern = ".xlsx", recursive = TRUE) and then for (i in files){
  import(i)
  }. But this didn't work, and now I just have lists of all the file names.

Comment: And was there a problem with that method? Note that `list.files` expects a regular expression for `pattern=`, not a glob. That pattern would not match excel files. Maybe `list.files(pattern = "xlsx$", recursive = TRUE, full.names=TRUE)` is what you meant. And `import()` is not the correct way to read excel files. You need a package like [readxl](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/)

Comment: `list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)` I think you will need a * in your pattern. After you get the list you have to read them in (most likely with an lapply)

Comment: As Mike says, you need both `recursive = TRUE` and `full.names = TRUE`, otherwise the folders are not included in the paths.

Comment: @Mike the `pattern=` argument takes a regular expression, not a glob. That won't work in R.

Comment: Thanks everyone! As per the advice of @MrFlick and Mike I have the list of the .xlsx files in the folder. Now I just need to be able to import them or extract data from specific cells. Is there a way to do this once I have the list?

Comment: @ThomasReid you can import them all at once as is like so: `lapply(list_of_files, read_xlsx)`